# Beamer: Show frame if it is defined

Tags: beamer, conditionals, include, programming

When constructing larger presentations with `beamer`, I often split them into several files on which I work individually.  For the sake of an MWE, it might look something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\include{foo1}
\include{foo2}
\end{document}
```

where `foo1.tex` contains

```
\begin{frame}[label=myslide]{Title}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

and `foo2.tex` looks like this:

```
\againframe<2>{myslide}
```

But if I now add `\includeonly{foo2}` to my main document, I'll of course get an error.  I usually circumvent these problems by putting the definition of `myslide` in a third file `foo0.tex` using the overlay specifier `<0>` which I load with `input` instead of `include` and by using `againframe` in both `foo1.tex` and `foo2.tex`.

However, I was wondering if there is some kind of TeX magic which enables me to say in `foo2.tex` something like: "Repeat frame `myslide` *if* it is defined and otherwise do nothing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the error with a warning:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@@@againframe<#1>[#2][#3]#4{%
  \@ifundefined{beamer@again@#4}%
  {\ClassWarning{beamer}{No frame has been designated to resume under
      the name "#4"}{}}%
  {%
  \def\beamer@temp{\frame<#1>[#2][{#3,relabel=#4}]}%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\beamer@templet\csname beamer@again@#4\endcsname%
  \expandafter\beamer@temp\beamer@templet}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{foo1.tex}
\begin{frame}[label=myslide]{Title}
  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{foo2.tex}
\againframe<2>{myslide}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\includeonly{foo2} 

\begin{document}



\include{foo1}
\include{foo2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I have to keep track of the definitions manually.  I was hoping for a more "elegant" solution that could directly check for the label without the need for explicit definitions.

Comment: @Frunobulax See my updated answer

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I wanted.